# error while fetching extensions xhr failed

Tags: visual, studio, proxy

Actualmente al querer instalar una extension desde la aplicacion de visual studio me salta el siguiente error;
error while fetching extensions xhr failed.
se que hay formas de hacerlo manual pero quiero lograr una solucion.
He estado mirando desde la aplicacion ajustes>proxy y probar las diferentes soluciones que he visto por internet.
He desinstalado toda la aplicación y borrando carpetas y sigo con el mismo problema.
Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.